# How to convert character to upper case using perl regex and | operator with gsub in R

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have the following strings:

```
x = c("123 w. main ave., city, st", "mr. smith", "456 main st.")
```

I want to be able to capitalize certain portions of the string that I know should be capitalized. I thought I could achieve this using `gsub` and `perl` with the following approach:

```
gsub("(m)(rs?\\. )|( a)(ve\\.[\\s,])|( s)(t\\.[\\s,$])", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl=T)
```

However, this results in the following:

```
# [1] "123 w. main city, st" "Mr. smith"            "456 main"
```

In the first string, it removed the text that it matched because the regex groups that were matched in that string were `\\3` and `\\4`. In the second string it works as intended since it matched groups `\\1` and `\\2`. In the third string it did the same as the first for the same reason.

My desired outcome would be the following:

```
# [1] "123 w. main Ave., city, st", "Mr. smith", "456 main St."
```

My question, then, is how do you tell regex to replace with the groups that it found? Do I have to do a different regex for each instance?

Comment: Is `$` supposed to be the end of string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, but am now realizing that it would actually be the dollar sign since `[ ]` removes special affects on the characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a [**branch reset group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) (`(?|...|...)`) and since the `$` seems to denote the end of string, you need an alternation group `(?:[\s,]|$)` rather than `[\s,$]` character class.

See

```
x = c("123 w. main ave., city, st", "mr. smith", "456 main st.")
gsub("(?|(m)(rs?\\. )|( a)(ve\\.[\\s,])|( s)(t\\.(?:[\\s,]|$)))", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl=T)
## => [1] "123 w. main Ave., city, st" "Mr. smith" "456 main St."
```

See [this online R demo](http://ideone.com/fr669r)

Thanks to the branch reset group, all the capturing groups inside the group are indexed starting with 1 in each separate branch.

Comment: You never cease to impress with your regex skills. Thanks!